# Python send string as argument to function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to make a text pattern using Python, but I am a little stuck on how to use main() function And send "string" argument to another function "d_func".
Plus if the text is long then 9 I want to slice it.

```
def d_func(a):
    length = len(a)
for i in range (0, length,2):
    for j in range(length-i//2):
        print(' ', end="")
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        print(word[j], end="")
    print()

for i in range (length - 3,-1,-2):
    for j in range(length-i//2):
        print(' ', end="")
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        print(word[j], end="")
    print()

def main():
    text = input("Enter text: ")
    if len(text) > 9 :
        text[:9]      ## slice the text if it bigger then 9 letters
    d_func(text)
main()
```

why i get " 'length' is not defined" error?

Comment: your indent are not correct. The _for_ loops are out of the function *d_func* Also *word* must be *a*

Comment: Could you also please show the input, the expected output, and the exact error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why i get " 'length' is not defined" error?

because your indent are not correct. The *for* loops are out of the function *d_func* so *length* is not defined.

> Plus if the text is long then 9 I want to slice it.

your line

> *text[:9]*

just extract the first 9 characters of *text* and loose it immediately, probably you want

```
 text = text[:9]
```

If you want to get up to last 9 letters use *text[-9:]* rather than *text[:9]*

Note you can also call *d_func* directly with *text[:9]*  without doing the test on the length.

Also in your code *word* must be *a*

After corrections :

```
def d_func(a):
    length = len(a)
    for i in range (0, length,2):
        for j in range(length-i//2):
            print(' ', end="")
        for j in range(0, i+1):
            print(a[j], end="")
        print()

    for i in range (length - 3,-1,-2):
        for j in range(length-i//2):
            print(' ', end="")
        for j in range(0, i+1):
            print(a[j], end="")
        print()

def main():
    text = input("Enter text: ")
    d_func(text[:9])

main()
```

Execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ python3 a.py 
Enter text: the long text
         t
        the
       the l
      the lon
     the long 
      the lon
       the l
        the
         t
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Note you can simplify a lot your code:

- to write the first *i+1* letters of the text it is useless to use a loop, just do *print(a[0:i+1])*
- to indent with *length-i//2* spaces you can use ' '*(length-i//2)

So

```
def d_func(a):
    length = len(a)
    for i in range (0, length,2):
        print(' '*(length-i//2), a[0:i+1], sep='')

    for i in range (length - 3,-1,-2):
        print(' '*(length-i//2), a[0:i+1], sep='')

def main():
    text = input("Enter text: ")
    d_func(text[:9])
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send to `d_func` a sliced string as a parameter:

```
text = input("Enter text: ")
d_func(text[:9])
...
```